# Reuse screen in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native and trying to set up a navigation between two screens (or pages) using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) package. I'm using a `StackNavigator` right now.

The problem I am facing is that there seems to be no way to navigate back to a previous screen. All I can do is call `navigate()`. If, for example, I want to navigate from `Home` to `FRW` and back to `Home`, it seems this will leave me with two instances of `Home` on the stack that are executed in parallel (one of which can't be seen). My code is something like this:

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './views/HomeScreen.js'
import FRWScreen from './views/FRWScreen.js'

  const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
    FRW: { screen: FRWScreen },
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  }, {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    headerVisible: false,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  });

export default class TestApp extends Component {  
  render() {    
    return (
      <MainNavigator></MainNavigator>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome'
  };

  (...)

  onSomeButtonPressed() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('FRW');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.locationWatchID !== undefined) return;

    this.locationWatchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      console.log(this.locationWatchID);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.locationWatchID);
  }

render() {
  (...)

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }} />
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.someButton}
          onPress={this.onSomeButtonPressed.bind(this)}
        >
          <Text>Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**FRWScreen.js looks similar to HomeScreen.js (and contains `.navigate("Home")`)**

The result of this code is, after navigating to FRW and back, that the geolocation callback is executed twice with different watchIDs. Which makes me believe the HomeScreen is actually on the navigation stack twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `FRWScreen` you should use `this.props.navigation.goBack(null)` instead. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#goBack-Close-the-active-screen-and-move-back.

Comment: that works perfectly. I have been searching the docs for forever but did not stumble across this method. Thank you!